# is there any games which give the concept of data structures to player during playing ??

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, tree, queue

i have to implement the data structure concept in games so user can clear their concepts by playing it for example tower of Hanoi give the concept of stack during playing. is there anymore games which give the concepts tree,queue,link-list,arrays of data structures.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you exactly want? Especially that "so user can clear their concepts by playing it" part.

Comment: @FilipRistic its just like a game that is tower of hanoi that will clear the concepts of stack

Answer (score 0):

Many games can implement data structures that you mentioned. Few examples:

Chess - can make use of hashmap for storing piece position, arraylist for storing list of possible moves of selected figure etc.

Word meaning game - hashmap where you put 2 strings, 1st is word and 2nd is word meaning

Words in foreign language - same like previous but you put some word lets say in French and equivalent in English or other way around.

Some quiz - make class Question with String question, String answers[], String correctAns and int difficulty, make comparator for class, then put questions inside treeset which will automatically order them by difficulty.